# Portable Application (Software) for reading Epub in Windows XP

Tags: portable, ebook, epub

I need a program that can display EPUB documents and which does NOT need to be instaleld (i.e., portable application) for Windows XP.

I've seen other similar threads: https://superuser.com/questions/183241/epub-reader-for-windows but the recommended software (Adobe Digital Editions) must be installed. I need something that can be used from a USB stick and that I don't require Administrator privileges to install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Portable_Apps](http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Portable_Apps) is a good list of portable ebook readers.